# Calculate stopptime

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I need to calculate the downtime of each day and present it in a monthly sheet. As a newbie, I have done two questions, because I don´t want them to be too complex.

The SQL Server CE database consist of the following columns:

- Time (Datetime)
- Start (Datetime)
- Stopp (Datetime)
- Orsak (Reason, Int)
- Arbetstid (Worktime, Int)

The first question is to calculate the day's downtime and looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Datepart("d", Time) AS Dag, 
    Sum(Datediff("s", Stopp, Start)) AS Stopptid
FROM
    Stopptid_Månad
GROUP BY
    Datepart("d", Time)
ORDER BY 
    Time
```

The second question is to select the working hours of the day and looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART("d", Time) AS Datum, Arbetstid
FROM 
    Stopptid_Månad
WHERE 
    Orsak = 20 
    AND DATEPART("h", Time) > 23
ORDER BY 
    Time
```

The result is presented in an Excel spreadsheet and I want it to look like this:

```
Datum   Arbetstid   Stopptid
  1         8h          120m
  2         6h          90m
 ...
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Added. Didn´t find the correct one at first.